# RecyclerView not properly displaying, despite showing properly in layout.xml's "design" mode

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

As in the title, in the  tab where it shows design/text I selected design. Everything looks fine and the recylclerView seems like it should be displayed. When I run it however my layout is empty. No bugs.

To debug, I've put a button in the middle of recycler_view_item and it displays once at the top. Also I've played around with individual textViews and imageViews and they're not displaying properly either.

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycler_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:contentDescription="TODO" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="285dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem[4:10]"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:text="@tools:sample/date/hhmm"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expected to view the recyclerView but it was just empty.

Comment: ?? I need to code Java too to make it work??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Yes, you need to set a ```layout manager``` and an ```adapter``` for ```recyclerView``` . See this link for a tutorial -> https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example